# Integrated CMS Based Off Model for Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, rails-activerecord

I have a site nearing structural completion. Essentially, it's made up of Users and Photos. However, Photos have a LOT of HABTM relationships, most of which are different kinds of tags, and others being categories, collections, etc...

My client would like to be able to have a conditional CMS based off the content being viewed for different promotional purposes or whatnot. For example, if a user is browsing the Category "Leprechauns", he may want to show html content about St. Patrick's Day or something. He may even want to easily include the browing user's name, if available. In which case, it'd be nice to have some sort of templating system. The part that makes this tricky is that these are small blocks of HTML for something like a 300x300 space in the sidebar and is NOT the primary content.

I've looked into refinery, but it seems to be too much of a complete solution. I've also thought about building in from scratch, but I don't know where to begin with treating dynamically generated pages (such as a new Category) as a recognizable object in Rails. I'd like to keep it more global than a slew of HABTM relationships, but it's looking like that might be where I'm heading. Ideally, he'd be able to make some HTML and check off "I'd like this to show on x and y Category page and b and z Collection page and for the tag Foo and for the tag bar as well as on my homepage"

Any suggestions? I'm open to finding a gem or getting a solid start on a homebrew.

**UPDATE**

I'm thinking of setting up some models Like the following:

```
cms_contents
============
id:integer
contents:text
timestamps

cms_associations
================
id:integer
cms_content_id:integer
model_id:integer
record_id:integer #optional
secondary_model_id:integer #optional
secondary_record_id:integer #optional

models
======
id:integer
name:string
```

Where:

- `cms_content` would contain the HTML.
- `cms_associations` would be an ActiveRecord model using `has_many, :through`
- `models` would contain a the models the CMS content could be associated with
- if `record_id` is not given, it associates with the model index
- if `record_id` *is* given, it associated with the record of the provided model with that
  id
- if secondary information is given, a combination is created for other many to many 
  relationships

eg:

```
User has_many :photos
Browsing Photos for User(10)
model_id => #User model Id
record_id => 10
secondary_model_id => #Photo model id
```

So you could customize the content for browsing photos for specific users such as featured users or companies that may pay for advertising.

Any thoughts on this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost as if the almighty Ryan Bates is looking out for me, but the latest Railscast is on CopyCopter, which does exactly what I'm looking for, and runs as a separate app, so I don't have to worry about bogging down my main app. I suggest anyone who finds this to watch the screencast, as it seems pretty impressive.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter?autoplay=true

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not that complicated. This is what you should do:

- Introduce new object in the DB, name it **htmlchunks**
- For every object that you'd want to associate with **htmlchunks**, create a **join table** and define **habtm** relationship
- Modify your sidebar (for objects that have association with **htmlchunks**) in a way that they recognize whether there's **htmlchunk** associated with this particular object. For example, let's say you have a **htmlchunk** called "April Fools' Day" that contains simple html paragraph. In the sidebar, you'd just ask something like @category.htmlchunk? and output according to the result. You'd ideally place all this in a partial
- As for creation of the **htmlchunks** you'd just offer simple wisiwig editor and ability to select any number of tags, categories, whatever. You'd create habtm entries between them and **htmlchunks** during the creation process

Let me know if you have further questions in the comments.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but not only will I have a slew of HABTM join tables (I think I figured somewhere around 20-25), but Then there would have to be some jimmying to associate with the model directly. (eg Browsing all categories) or special conditions like browsing Tag "foo" for user "Baz". That last one might be overtly complex regardless, I'm thinking.

Comment: 1) Do you really have 20-25 other tables that you'd associate with your html chunks? You mentioned categories, tags and maybe something else. Even if you do, I do not think that it's a big problem.

Comment: 2) As for special conditions like displaying this htmlchunk for this tag to these user(s): in the habtm join table that associates this chunk with that tag, you'd just add user_ids fields that would contain IDs of users that creator of the chunk selects during the creation. Then you'd just use simple logical statements to determine who is supposed to see this chunk on this tag.

Comment: Well, yeah. I'm thinking most of my models will be associated with this model so that the content can be managed throughout the entire site. I'm starting to think I might assign IDs to each model table and make an intense has_many through table that handles all the models

Comment: I'd say habtm is more effective in this case since it gives you more flexibility for additional rules that you might employ for display of the html chunks.

Comment: VS has many through? My understanding is that HABTM is limited to two ID columns on the join, which is far less flexible.

Comment: It's not limited to anything. It **requires** ids of two objects that you are associating, by Rails conventions. However, that does not mean that you cannot add more fields to be able to solve your problem in an efficient way.